# Google api oauth url

Tags: api

I have received the oauth from the google. Now I need to request for getting token. Can any one out here help me out to know what is the url and parameter I need to generate. 
When I go through the doc I found this information regarding the token request. I am using

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token as my endpoint url.
>
> ```
>  POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>  Host: accounts.google.com
>  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>  code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
>  client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
>  client_secret={client_secret}&
>  redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
>  grant_type=authorization_code
> ```

But get confused with the url with which the request need to be send.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

Comment: but here they are not mentioning url for token request after oauth is received.

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters are required for getting token as a response from google